# Recursively filter array of objects with different properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, filter

I have a object with others arrays. I need to filter when in the main array match RazaoSocial:"AAS" or Produtos:[{Descricao:"AAS"}]

That's my code:

```
var input = [
  {
    RazaoSocial: 'AAS',
    Produtos: [
    { DescricaoProduto: 'XXX', id:12, other:"other text" },
      { DescricaoProduto: 'YYY', id:12, other:"other text" }
    ]
  },
  {
    RazaoSocial: 'I found you',
    Produtos: [
      { DescricaoProduto: 'AAS', id:12, other:"other text" },
      { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id:12, other:"other text" },
      { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id:12, other:"other text" },
      { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id:99, other:"other text" }      
    ]
  },
  {
    RazaoSocial: 'bla',
    Produtos: [
        { DescricaoProduto: 'AB', id:12, other:"other text" },
        { DescricaoProduto: 'CD', id:12, other:"other text" },
    ]
  },  
];

var res = input.filter(function f(o) {
    if (o.RazaoSocial.includes("AAS")) return true
    if (o.Produtos.DescricaoProduto) {
        console.log(o.Produtos);
        return (o.Produtos = o.Produtos.filter(f)).length
    }
})
 console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

//result

```
[
  {
    "RazaoSocial": "AAS",
    "Produtos": [
      {
        "DescricaoProduto": "XXX",
        "id": 12,
        "other": "other text"
      },
      {
        "DescricaoProduto": "YYYAAS",
        "id": 12,
        "other": "other text"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Why the object with "i found you" it's not returned ? I was expeting

```
[
        {
            RazaoSocial: 'AAS',
            Produtos: [
                { DescricaoProduto: 'XXX', id: 12, other: "other text" },
                { DescricaoProduto: 'YYY', id: 12, other: "other text" }
            ]
        },
        {
            RazaoSocial: 'I found you',
            Produtos: [
                { DescricaoProduto: 'AAS', id: 12, other: "other text" },
                { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id: 12, other: "other text" },
                { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id: 12, other: "other text" },
                { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id: 99, other: "other text" }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I tried the examples in, but with no success.
[Recursively filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132146/recursively-filter-array-of-objects)

What I'm doing wrong ?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with the original attempt was the `if (o.Produtos.DescricaoProduto) {`

`o.Produtos` is an array so you cannot access `o.Produtos.DescricaoProduto` without first getting an index.

So since `o.Produtos` is an array we can go ahead and filter it like we did the original input.

I've added both a recursive and non-recursive approach you could compare.

The recursive solution is entirely generic and can find any given value.

```js
var input = [
  {
    RazaoSocial: 'AAS',
    Produtos: [
      { DescricaoProduto: 'XXX', id:12, other:"other text" },
      { DescricaoProduto: 'YYY', id:12, other:"other text" }
    ]
  },
  {
    RazaoSocial: 'I found you',
    Produtos: [
      { DescricaoProduto: 'AAS', id:12, other:"other text" },
      { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id:12, other:"other text" },
      { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id:12, other:"other text" },
      { DescricaoProduto: 'Miss8', id:99, other:"other text" }      
    ]
  },
  {
    RazaoSocial: 'bla',
    Produtos: [
        { DescricaoProduto: 'AB', id:12, other:"other text" },
        { DescricaoProduto: 'CD', id:12, other:"other text" },
    ]
  },  
];

var useRecursive = true, 
    res;
if (useRecursive) {
  var findValue = function (str) {
      return function(o) {
          return Object.values(o).filter(function (value) {
              if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                  return value.filter(findValue(str)).length > 0
              } else {
                  return value.toString().includes(str)
              }
          }).length > 0;
      };
  };
  res = input.filter(findValue("AAS"))

} else {
  res = input.filter(function f(o) {
    if (o.RazaoSocial.includes("AAS")) return true
    if (o.Produtos.length) {
        return o.Produtos.filter(function(o1) {
          return o1.DescricaoProduto.includes("AAS");
        }).length;
    }
  })
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

Comment: Care to leave some commentary on why your code works? Will consider an upvote if so.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = input.map(function f(o) {
var _ret = false;
if (o.RazaoSocial.includes("AAS")) _ret  = true
if (o.Produtos.DescricaoProduto) {
    console.log(o.Produtos);
    _ret  = (o.Produtos = o.Produtos.filter(f)).length
}
return _ret; 
})
```

I haven't test this make use of above

Answer (score 0):

No recursion needed here. Use a simple filter something like:

```
var res = input.filter(function (o) {
 return o.RazaoSocial.includes("AAS") ||
   o.Produtos && o.Produtos.find(function (p) {
     return p.DescricaoProduto === 'AAS';
 }));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

At least I think that's what you're after! It should leave you with all the objects in the array where RazaoSocial matches 'AAS' or any of the Produtos have DescriaoProduto == 'AAS'.