# Angular/Typescript - filter all matching objects in object and its exactly same children

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following example array of objects:

```
[
  {
    id: "aaa",
    name: "aaa",
    children: [],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "abc",
    name: "abc",
    children: [
      {
        id: "abc/aaa",
        name: "aaa",
        children: [],
        groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
        itemCount: 0,
      },
      {
        id: "abc/AAA podgrupa",
        name: "AAA podgrupa",
        children: [
          {
            id: "abc/AAA podgrupa/AAA",
            name: "AAA",
            children: [],
            groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
            itemCount: 0,
          },
          {
            id: "abc/AAA podgrupa/asd",
            name: "asd",
            children: [
              {
                id: "abc/AAA podgrupa/asd/AAAA",
                name: "AAAA",
                children: [],
                groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
                itemCount: 0,
              },
              {
                id: "abc/AAA podgrupa/asd/asd",
                name: "asd",
                children: [],
                groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
                itemCount: 0,
              },
            ],
            groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
            itemCount: 0,
          },
        ],
        groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
        itemCount: 0,
      },
    ],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "asd",
    name: "asd",
    children: [],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "DYN_TST2",
    name: "DYN_TST2",
    children: [],
    groupSpec: {
      className: "Dynamic",
      filterIds: ["6ede6576-11ac-493f-b910-8f0a668fd51c"],
    },
  },
  {
    id: "grupa0_CWU",
    name: "grupa0_CWU",
    children: [],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "TEST_BIURKO",
    name: "TEST_BIURKO",
    children: [
      {
        id: "TEST_BIURKO/AAAAPOD",
        name: "AAAAPOD",
        children: [],
        groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
        itemCount: 0,
      },
    ],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 1,
  },
  {
    id: "test_CWU",
    name: "test_CWU",
    children: [],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 1,
  },
  {
    id: "TEST_CWU2",
    name: "TEST_CWU2",
    children: [],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 1,
  },
];
```

I have input that listens to changes and I want to filter these objects by name property, so the array returns all matching objects, including objects with name that do not match, but their childs/childrens name does.

For example: if I type into the input "aaa" (info: letter size doesn't matter, its lower cased), it should return:

```
[
  {
    id: "aaa",
    name: "aaa",
    children: [],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "abc",
    name: "abc",
    children: [
      {
        id: "abc/aaa",
        name: "aaa",
        children: [],
        groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
        itemCount: 0,
      },
      {
        id: "abc/AAA podgrupa",
        name: "AAA podgrupa",
        children: [
          {
            id: "abc/AAA podgrupa/AAA",
            name: "AAA",
            children: [],
            groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
            itemCount: 0,
          },
          {
            id: "abc/AAA podgrupa/asd",
            name: "asd",
            children: [
              {
                id: "abc/AAA podgrupa/asd/AAAA",
                name: "AAAA",
                children: [],
                groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
                itemCount: 0,
              },
            ],
            groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
            itemCount: 0,
          },
        ],
        groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
        itemCount: 0,
      },
    ],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "TEST_BIURKO",
    name: "TEST_BIURKO",
    children: [
      {
        id: "TEST_BIURKO/AAAAPOD",
        name: "AAAAPOD",
        children: [],
        groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
        itemCount: 0,
      },
    ],
    groupSpec: { className: "Static" },
    itemCount: 1,
  },
];
```

Notice that even tho the parents name doesn't match - its children does, so it should return the parent with all matching children and therefore, childrens children too.

I have the following code:

```
   this.groupNameSearch.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      const searchedPhrase = value.toLowerCase();

      this.groups = _.cloneDeep(this.allGroups).filter((group) => {
        const matchedGroup = group.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchedPhrase);
        group.children = group.children.filter((child) => child.name?.toLowerCase().includes(searchedPhrase));

        return matchedGroup || group.children.length;
      });
    });
```

It works, but only for the parent, and its direct children. These objects structures are exactly the same for parent and children. The app can add nest infinite/large amounts of these objects.

Comment: What you want is a recursive filtering function. There are lots of examples of similar questions here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=filter+array+recursively. I think this may match your use case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876567/recursively-filter-array-of-objects-with-different-properties

Answer (score 0):

As comment above suggests, your code is lacking recursivity: you should create a separate function for filtering children. This is a simplified version I coded, without listeners and a fixed string filter ('aaa'), I think it gets the result you expected:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("allGroups length: " + this.allGroups.length);
    this.filteredGroups = this.filterGroups(this.allGroups);
    this.filteredGroups.forEach(gr => {
      if(gr.children.length>0){
        let children = gr.children;
        gr.children = this.filterChildren(children);
      }
    });
    console.log(this.filteredGroups);
  }

  filterGroups(groups: Group[]) {
    let filtered = groups.filter((group) => {
      const matchedGroup = group.name?.toLowerCase().includes('aaa');
      if(matchedGroup && group.children.length==0){
        return true;
      }else if(group.children.length>0){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    return filtered;
  }

  filterChildren(groups: Group[]) {
    let filteredChildren = this.filterGroups(groups);
    filteredChildren.forEach(ch => {
      if (ch.children.length > 0) {
        ch.children = this.filterChildren(ch.children);
      }
    });
    return filteredChildren;
  }
```

Hope this helps!