# How to transform a nested array into string if it contains null values or just an empty one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, lodash

I need to replace nested arrays inside a main array that have null values like lets say `[null, null]` or the nested arrays that are empty with a string value like `"empty"`.

Saying that we have the following array:

```
array = [
  {
    id: 123, 
    name: 'Peter',
    phone: [null, null],
    addresses: [{ address1: 'Manchester, UK', address2: 'London, UK' }]
  },
  {
    id: 124,
    name: 'Sara',
    phone: [],
    addresses: [{ address1: 'London, UK', address2: 'Paris, FR' }]
  }
];
```

We see that, the first array has phone: `[null, null]` and the second has it as `[]`. What I need to do it to transform them into the following:

```
array = [
  {
    id: 123, 
    name: 'Peter',
    phone: "empty",
    addresses: [{ address1: 'Manchester, UK', address2: 'London, UK' }]
  },
  {
    id: 124,
    name: 'Sara',
    phone: "empty",
    addresses: [{ address1: 'London, UK', address2: 'Paris, FR' }]
  }
];
```

This is an example, and each array might contain multiple nested arrays that have the same `[null, null]` or `[]`.

I tried the following:

```
var filtered = this.array.map(subarray => subarray.filter(el => el != null));
```

from this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53436773/how-to-remove-null-values-from-nested-arrays?answertab=active#tab-top), but I've got an error saying:

> Error: subarray.filter is not a function

Then I tried a second method using `lodash's` `every()` and `isNull` method and property but couldn't figure it out:

```
let props = [];
props = Array.from(new Set(this.array.flatMap(e => Object.keys(e), [])));
console.log(props)
for (const prop of props) {
  this.array.forEach(e => {
    if ((Array.isArray(e[prop]) || typeof(e[prop]) === 'object') && e[prop]._.every(_.isNull)) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  });
}
```

I searched few questions on Stack Overflow but the structure of the arrays are like: `[ [1, 2], [1,3]...]` and not like my array's structure `[{...}, {...}]`, so I tried some of the solution and got the same error of method 1 above.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/null-nested-array-into-string-qk37mh).

Comment: will the `[]` or `[null, null]` array always be a value of the `phone` property or do you want to replace all occurrence of `[null, null]` throughout the entire object (regardless of what its property/key is)

Comment: Some users have already phone numbers, some don't. And I am giving an example about phone numbers here, but there is other fields in my data that may encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

First loop through the array, and within each object, you can set the phone property:

```
for(const entry of array) {
    const isEmpty = entry.phone.filter(p => p !== null).length === 0;
    entry.phone = isEmpty ? 'empty' : entry.phone;
}
```

Caveat is that this edits your array. One concern about the premise of the question is that you are setting an array property to a string, which is not ideal.

Live Example: https://jsfiddle.net/michaschwab/9ze3p2or/3/, and here's your edited stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/null-nested-array-into-string-jwhfwn

If you want to not modify your array, this is a way to do it:

```
const modified = array.map(entry => {
  return {...entry, // Copy previous values
    phone: entry.phone.filter(p => p !== null).length === 0 ? 'empty' : entry.phone
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The weird thing that I am keep getting ` Cannot read property 'filter' of null` on my visual studio code

Comment: I found out that when a field of an array even if it was not an array, like a string but with `null` as follow, here it is returning the error. Please consider that here the `phone` is an example, I need to loop over all the properties of my array that have type object of array and check if null or empty

Comment: Are you saying that the keys can also have null as value?

Answer (score 1):

Map the array, and use `_.mapValues()` on each object. For each values that is an array, and full of `null` values, return `'empty'`:

```js
const array = [{"id":123,"name":"Peter","phone":[null,null],"addresses":[{"address1":"Manchester, UK","address2":"London, UK"}]},{"id":124,"name":"Sara","phone":[],"addresses":[{"address1":"London, UK","address2":"Paris, FR"}]}];

const result = array.map(o => 
  _.mapValues(o, v => // map the values of the object
    _.isArray(v) && v.every(_.isNull) ? 'empty' : v // if a value is an array, and all values are null return 'empty'
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```