# How to multi level filter based on a property from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. Every object has `hasPermission` property and `children` property.
children property is also an array of objects and every object has `hasPermission` property.
My array like this:

```
const navigationMenus = [
  {
    hasPermission: false,
    name: 'Main',
    type: 'section',
    children: [
      {
        hasPermission: true,
        name: 'Test',
        type: 'item',
        link: '/test'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    hasPermission: true,
    name: 'Master',
    type: 'section',
    children: [
      {
        hasPermission: true,
        name: 'Operator Group',
        type: 'item',
        link: '/operator-group'
      },
      {
        hasPermission: false,
        name: 'Operation Group',
        type: 'item',
        link: '/operation-group'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Based on `hasPermission` property I want another array which holds only those objects which `hasPermission` property is true.
I tried with this approach.

```
const permittedNavigationMenus = []
for (let i = 0; i < navigationMenus.length; i++) {
  const section = navigationMenus[i];
  if (section.hasPermission) {
    const permittedSection = {
      name: section.name,
      type: section.type,
      children: []
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < section.children.length; j++) {
      const item = section.children[j]
      if (item.hasPermission) {
        permittedSection.children.push(item)
      }
    }
    permittedNavigationMenus.push(permittedSection)
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(permittedNavigationMenus, null, 2))
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that in a single pass using `.reduce()`:

```
const permittedNavigationMenus = navigationMenus.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => {
    if (cur.hasPermission) {
      acc.push({
        ...cur,
        children: cur.children.filter(({ hasPermission }) => hasPermission)
      })
    }

    return acc;
  },
  []
);
```

Comment: I've fallen in love on Array.reduce() method.

Answer (score 1):

a simple recursive function can do that:

```js
const navigationMenus = 
  [ { hasPermission: false, name: 'Main', type: 'section', children: 
      [ { hasPermission: true, name: 'Test', type: 'item', link: '/test' } ] 
    } 
  , { hasPermission: true, name: 'Master', type: 'section', children: 
      [ { hasPermission: true, name: 'Operator Group', type: 'item', link: '/operator-group' } 
      , { hasPermission: false, name: 'Operation Group', type: 'item', link: '/operation-group' } 
  ] } ] 

const navigationMenusTrue = []

function runArray(arr,parent)
  {
  arr.forEach(({children,...info}) => 
    {
    if (info.hasPermission)
      {
      let newRow = {...info}
      parent.push(newRow)
      if (children)
        {
        let xChilds = []
        newRow.children = xChilds
        runArray(children,xChilds)
        }
      }  
    })
  }

runArray(navigationMenus,navigationMenusTrue)

console.log( navigationMenusTrue )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an recursive option using [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const
  filterByPermission = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((a, o) => {
      if (o.hasPermission) {
        const _o = o?.children?.length
          ? { ...o, children: filterByPermission(o.children) }
          : { ...o };
        a.push(_o);
      }

      return a;
    }, [])
  },

  navigationMenus = [{ hasPermission: false, name: 'Main', type: 'section', children: [{ hasPermission: true, name: 'Test', type: 'item', link: '/test' }] }, { hasPermission: true, name: 'Master', type: 'section', children: [{ hasPermission: true, name: 'Operator Group', type: 'item', link: '/operator-group' }, { hasPermission: false, name: 'Operation Group', type: 'item', link: '/operation-group' }] }],
  result = filterByPermission(navigationMenus);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I am afraid of recursion.  Very complex thing. Have u any guideline which help me to understand recursion very well?

Answer (score 1):

Need to use recursion

```js
const navigationMenus = [
  {
    hasPermission: false,
    name: 'Main',
    type: 'section',
    children: [
      {
        hasPermission: true,
        name: 'Test',
        type: 'item',
        link: '/test'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    hasPermission: true,
    name: 'Master',
    type: 'section',
    children: [
      {
        hasPermission: true,
        name: 'Operator Group1',
        type: 'item',
        link: '/operator-group'
      },
      {
        hasPermission: false,
        name: 'Operation Group2',
        type: 'item',
        link: '/operation-group',
        children: [
          {
            hasPermission: true,
            name: 'Operator Group3',
            type: 'item',
            link: '/operator-group'
          },
          {
            hasPermission: false,
            name: 'Operation Group4',
            type: 'item',
            link: '/operation-group'
          }
    ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function filterRec(arr = []) {
    return arr.map(el => {
        const elem = el.hasPermission && el
        const children = filterRec(el.children)

        const result = ({ ...elem, ...(children.length && ({children}) || {}) })
        return Object.keys(result).length && result
    }).filter(Boolean)
}

   // or without empty children key
// /function filterRec(arr = []) {
// return arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
//     let result = el.hasPermission && el

//     const children = filterRec(el.children)
//     if (result && children.length) {
//         result.children = children
//     } else if (!result) {
//         result = children
//     }

//     return acc.concat(result).filter(Boolean)
// }, [])
// }
console.log(filterRec(navigationMenus))
```

Probably answered [Recursively filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132146/recursively-filter-array-of-objects)